# DragSortListView and highlighting items

Tags: android, android-listview, drag-and-drop, highlight

I'm using the wonderful [DragSortListView](https://github.com/bauerca/drag-sort-listview). The list is populated by a CursorAdapter using Mike Murphy's [SQLiteCursorLoader](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-loaderex).

My question is how to highlight an item/row on click, and then keep it highlighted after drag&drop or remove in the list.

I've tried regular xml manipulation with selectors for item background, but the highlight won't persist over drag&drop.
I've also tried setting the background of items in the adaptor's bindView(), but since each of drop() and the CursorLoader call swapCursor() on the adapter, the highlighted row flickers. This solution seems dirty anyway.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using the following [post](http://jasonmcreynolds.com/?p=423).